# Built-in method/library to solve optimization problem in Julia

Tags: julia, libraries, mathematical-optimization, minimization

I am looking for a built-in library or function to solve a minimization problem in Julia. Namely, I have a large function of 10 parameters that I want to feed into a solver, and I want to find the specific values of those 10 parameters that simultaneously minimize that function. I noticed that there is [an introduction to the simplex method in the "Julia Programming for Operations Research"](https://www.softcover.io/read/7b8eb7d0/juliabook/simplex), but this minimization is a small portion of my overall project and I would prefer to use some built-in feature, library, or pre-made function GitHub to get some quick-and-dirty results as fast as possible. Does such a Julia library exist?

Comment: From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, *software library*, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." (emphasis added)

Comment: There are many optimization libraries in Julia. JuMP is one of the best and best-known, but maybe you can do with something more lightweight. What kind of problem do you need to solve, linear or non-linear, being the most obvious distinction? Personally, I tend to use Optim.jl for non-linear problems.

Comment: You may want to give more details about how this function looks like. E.g. if it is linear, quadratic and convex, non-linear etc.

Answer (score 3):

You use `JuMP` and a solver e.g. `Cbc` for that:

```
using JuMP, Cbc
m = Model(Cbc.Optimizer)
@variable(m, 0 <= x[i=1:10] <= 7)
@constraint(m, sum(x) == 15)

@objective(m, Max, sum(i*x[i] for i in 1:10))

optimize!(m)
```

You can print your model:

```
julia> println(m)
Max x[1] + 2 x[2] + 3 x[3] + 4 x[4] + 5 x[5] + 6 x[6] + 7 x[7] + 8 x[8] + 9 x[9] + 10 x[10]
Subject to
 x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5] + x[6] + x[7] + x[8] + x[9] + x[10] == 15.0
 x[1] >= 0.0
 x[2] >= 0.0
 x[3] >= 0.0
 x[4] >= 0.0
 x[5] >= 0.0
 x[6] >= 0.0
 x[7] >= 0.0
 x[8] >= 0.0
 x[9] >= 0.0
 x[10] >= 0.0
 x[1] <= 7.0
 x[2] <= 7.0
 x[3] <= 7.0
 x[4] <= 7.0
 x[5] <= 7.0
 x[6] <= 7.0
 x[7] <= 7.0
 x[8] <= 7.0
 x[9] <= 7.0
 x[10] <= 7.0
```

This is how you solve it:

```
julia> optimize!(m)
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver
Version: 2.10.3
Build Date: Jan  1 1970

command line - Cbc_C_Interface -solve -quit (default strategy 1)
Presolve 1 (0) rows, 10 (0) columns and 10 (0) elements
0  Obj -0 Primal inf 15 (1) Dual inf 54.999999 (10)
1  Obj 141
Optimal - objective value 141
Optimal objective 141 - 1 iterations time 0.002
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.01   (Wallclock seconds):       0.01
```

And this is how you get the values of your variable:

```
julia> value.(x)
10-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 1.0
 7.0
 7.0
```